# Difference between NOT_HANDSHAKING and FINISHED

Tags: java, ssl

**Q1:** What is the difference between the states **NOT_HANDSHAKING** and **FINISHED** in the enum SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus of the SSLEngine ?

Javadoc just says

**FINISHED**: The SSLEngine has just finished handshaking.

**NOT_HANDSHAKING**: The SSLEngine is not currently handshaking.

In particular I wonder:

**Q2:** If the initial handshake has been performed successfully, should the engine be in state FINISHED or in state NOT_HANDSHAKING ?

What makes me suspicious is: The sample code SSLChannel.java to [this article](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html), tells

```
case NOT_HANDSHAKING: 
     assert false : "doHandshake() should never reach the NOT_HANDSHAKING state";
```

while in my sample program the initial handshake seems to finish with the state NOT_HANDSHAKING. So I don't know if this is OK or it's an errorneous state. Also the official [JSSE Refernce Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) is of no help since it merely says

```
// Handle other status:  // FINISHED or NOT_HANDSHAKING
    ...
```

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: each wrap/unwrap may change the handshake status. you should first see a FINISHED; afterwards, you should see NOT_HANDSHAKING - until the peer is trying to renegotiate.

Comment: I've done some ssl [coding](https://github.com/zhong-j-yu/bayou/blob/0.9/src/bayou/ssl/SslHandshaker.java#L200) in case you can reference.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'm curious to see how the handshake states will compare to my program.

Comment: Thanks @bayou.io, your code was very, very helpful. In fact, my mistake was: After unwrap() I had been checking engine.getHandshakeStatus() instead of result.getHandshakeStatus(). ---- I wanted to upvote your comments but there is no arrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- FINISHED means you have *just* finished, and it is only ever present in the handshake status object returned by `wrap()/unwrap()`.
- NOT_HANDSHAKING means there is no handshake in progress, and it is returned by both the status object mentioned above and by the status object returned by `getHandshakeStatus()`.

Comment: Thanks @EJP, your answer was very helpful in recognizing the critical difference in bayou.io's code and mine. Do you happen to know why the SSLEngine API uses two handshake status, i.e. engine.getHandshakeStatus() and result.getHandshakeStatus() ?

Comment: Just exactly so that it can implement this difference. I don't see any great need for FINISHED myself, but then I don't see any great need for the SSSLEngine either. They could have provided an SSLSocketChannel. It's hard, too hard for most implementors, but possible, and the JDK is where it should be provided.

Comment: Actually I like the SSLEngine's idea to seperate SSL/TLS logic from the transport mechanism. But from a user's point of view it would be simpler having just one hs status: A simple `switch(engine.getHandshakeStatus()) {...}` would do. But as it is designed now, one always have to care if engine.getHandshakeStatus or result.getHandshakeStatus has to be evaluated. Anyway, the API is as it is.

Comment: The answer to that is always to use the status returned by wrap/unwrap. No reason not to. The reasons advanced in the rationale for SSLEngine do not hold water. You don't need the separation you mention for any known purpose, and the Javadoc talks about the 'problem' of how to despatch tasks as though Executors hadn't been introduced in the same JDK version. I'd like to know the number of successful SSLEngine usages. I'm sure it is extremely low, in double figures at best.